# Java listener for a REST Call

Tags: java, rest

I have to write a java listener service for a response of a rest call. Then I am going to read the response json and do my own logic depend on the response fields.

Since i am going to use a external rest service, i am finding hard to think how pattern like observe and observable can apply this kind of situation.

How can i listen to the rest response?

Comment: Listening to a 3rd Party RESTful Web Service call or your own RESTful Web Service?

Comment: Listening to a 3rd Party RESTful Web Service call.

Comment: What do you use to connect to the REST API? Spring RestTemplate? Something else?

Comment: I use spring-web jar